# Cannot access form field in Struts 2 action

Tags: struts2

I have an input in Struts 2 form like this:

```
<s:form action="Action">
  <input type="text" value="v01" name="name01"/>
</s:form>
```

The problem is when I tried to `getParameter("name01")` I get `null`.

How can I access this parameter in my action? I implemented both `ServletRequestAware` and `ServletResponseAware`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add getters/setters in your Action class for the form inputs.